# Can the compiler optimize out the initialization of a static local variable?

Tags: c++, static, compiler-optimization

what should be the behavior in the following case:

```
class C {
    boost::mutex mutex_;
    std::map<...> data_;
};

C& get() {
    static C c;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    get(); // is compiler free to optimize out the call? 
    ....
}
```

is compiler allowed to optimize out the call to `get()`?

the idea was to touch static variable to initialize it before multithreaded operations needed it

is this a better option?:

```
C& get() {
    static C *c = new C();
    return *c;
}
```

Comment: Are the constructor and destructor of `C` trivial?

Comment: @James in my case no, they have mutex and map

Comment: even if the constructors are non-trivial, ::get::c is static, they get called in the same manner regardless of the call to `::get()`,  the compiler could correctly optimize that call out without otherwise harming the functionality.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy:  The compiler (and linker, probably) would have to ensure that the `get()` in `main()` is the first call to `get()`; this won't be the case if `get()` is called during dynamic initialization of static objects at namespace scope.

Comment: It is allowed to optimize away the actual call as long as there is no change in behavior.

Comment: How would the presence of a mutex affect the behavior of ::get()?  as written, get does NOTHING with c, besides return a reference to it.(not much different from a pointer).  To put it another way, why do you care if there is a function call there?

Comment: @Tok, well, the idea was to touch static variable to initialize it before multithreaded operations needed it

Comment: are you sure you don't want: `C& get() {
    static C *c; if (!c) c = new C();
    return *c;
}`

Comment: @Tok i thought for static vars its not needed, they get inited once

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right about the initialization(in fact, the generated one is better, since it will use cpu guard instructions), but you still aren't returning the correct type.

Comment: @Tok oh right, forgot to deref

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated (2023) Answer:

In C++23 (N4950) any side effects of initializing a static local variable are observable as its containing block is entered. As such, unless the compiler can determine that initializing the variable has no visible side effects, it will have to generate code for to call `get()` at the appropriate time (or to execute an inlined version of `get()`, as the case may be).

Contrary to earlier standards, C++ 23 no longer gives permission for dynamic initialization of a static local variable to be done "early" (as discussed below).

[stmt.dcl]/3:

> Dynamic initialization of a block variable with static storage duration (6.7.5.2) or thread storage duration
> (6.7.5.3) is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered
> initialized upon the completion of its initialization.

## Original (2010) answer:

The C and C++ standards operate under a rather simple principle generally known as the "as-if rule" -- basically, that the compiler is free to do almost anything as long as no conforming code can discern the difference between what it did and what was officially required.

I don't see a way for conforming code to discern whether `get` was actually called in this case, so it looks to me like it's free to optimize it out.

At least as recently as N4296, the standard contained explicit permission to do early initialization of static local variables:

> Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a
> block-scope entity with static storage duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first entered.
> An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or
> thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize
> a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable is
> initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon
> the completion of its initialization.

So, under this rule, initialization of the local variable could happen arbitrarily early in execution, so even if it has visible side effects, they're allowed to happen before any code that attempts to observed them. As such, you aren't guaranteed to see them, so optimizing it out is allowed.

Comment: I don't understand how the compiler could know that `get` doesn't perform any side effect... and thus how it could decide to optimize it. Unless `get` is pure (and how would it know about it ?), there is no reason not to execute it... is it ?

Comment: @Matthieu: The C standard defines a side effect as modifying a volatile variable or calling a library function. It's pretty easy for a compiler to figure out that `get` does neither.

Comment: if the definition of get is visible within the translation unit, yet it is, but if it is defined within another translation unit, would this be subject to LTO ? I doubt it, but I don't know much about LTO yet.

Comment: @Matthieu: Hard to say -- from the viewpoint of the standard, there's no real separation between LTO and other optimization. That said, my guess would be that what usually gets called LTO wouldn't typically do this, but what gets called LTCG might.

Comment: If the `std::map` in `static C c` isn't constructed yet, the first call to `get()` will call `new` inside its constructor, which may make a system call to allocate memory as @MatthieuM. says.  (And replaceable-`new` is a constant pain for optimizers, potentially making `new` a visible side-effect.)  In practice even with everything in the same compilation unit (https://godbolt.org/z/WPv9Pxzs6 GCC13 with libstdc++ and clang17 with libc++), the construction / destruction is *not* optimized out, and it still checks the guard variable for the local `static`. (In case of code before `main`).

Comment: But yes, in theory if the constructors had no opaque functions or visible side-effects (I/O or volatile), a compiler *could* hypothetically omit construction.  A `static` local with a non-constant initializer like this will have a guard variable, so it's safe for it to be called by multiple threads in parallel as required by ISO C++.  (GCC has been doing so long before C++11, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/P3sjo4Tjd shows GCC4.1 using a guard variable and `__cxa_guard_acquire` if the guard doesn't indicate it was already constructed.)

Comment: Oops, correction, std::map construction doesn't call `new`.  I was looking at `std::unordered_map`, but a non-zero-size hash table with no entries is different from an empty tree.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I've updated the answer based on the current standard, and noted how the current standard differs from what was in place when I originally answered this.

Comment: I don't think the removal of being allowed to do it *earlier* is very significant.  Even in C++20 and earlier, it needed to run *as if* construction happened at that point or earlier, but the OP was asking if it could be deferred until the first call from some thread.  I posted an answer, that might be hypothetically possible, but one thing that might prevent it is destruction order of the `std::map<int,int>` nodes, because other data structures destructed later could hypothetically have references to the `int` objects contained in nodes.  (And also to show that it's thread safe to defer.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's almost certainly not significant to the example code, but could be to the headline question (which is considerably more general). If you're expecting side effects from the ctor at a specific time, it can make a difference. For example if `a()` and `b()` each construct a local static with side effects, under the current rules, `a(); b();` should produce the side effects in order, but under the old rules might not.

Comment: Indeed, my reading is that C++20 and earlier specifically allow *visible* side-effects to happen early (but not late).  Or any side-effects that might indirectly lead to I/O or whatever, like writing to non-volatile globals.  I guess even reading globals that might not even be initialized yet if done early?  C++23 requires all of that to happen as-if on first call, if there are any.  Everything else is still up to the as-if rule.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It is explicit that anything with mandatory static initialization will be zero-initialized before anything else happens. So any global you read will be initialized before you read it (but not necessarily initialized as the programmer intended).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your edits, here's an improved version, with the same results.

Input:

```
struct C { 
    int myfrob;
    int frob();
    C(int f);
 };
C::C(int f) : myfrob(f) {}
int C::frob() { return myfrob; }

C& get() {
    static C *c = new C(5);
    return *c;
}

int main() {
    return get().frob(); // is compiler free to optimize out the call? 

}
```

Output:

```
; ModuleID = '/tmp/webcompile/_28088_0.bc'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-linux-gnu"

%struct.C = type { i32 }

@guard variable for get()::c = internal global i64 0            ; <i64*> [#uses=4]

declare i32 @__cxa_guard_acquire(i64*) nounwind

declare i8* @operator new(unsigned long)(i64)

declare void @__cxa_guard_release(i64*) nounwind

declare i8* @llvm.eh.exception() nounwind readonly

declare i32 @llvm.eh.selector(i8*, i8*, ...) nounwind

declare void @__cxa_guard_abort(i64*) nounwind

declare i32 @__gxx_personality_v0(...)

declare void @_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow(i8*)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %0 = load i8* bitcast (i64* @guard variable for get()::c to i8*), align 8 ; <i8> [#uses=1]
  %1 = icmp eq i8 %0, 0                           ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %1, label %bb.i, label %_Z3getv.exit

bb.i:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %2 = tail call i32 @__cxa_guard_acquire(i64* @guard variable for get()::c) nounwind ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %2, 0                          ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %3, label %_Z3getv.exit, label %bb1.i

bb1.i:                                            ; preds = %bb.i
  %4 = invoke i8* @operator new(unsigned long)(i64 4)
          to label %invcont.i unwind label %lpad.i ; <i8*> [#uses=2]

invcont.i:                                        ; preds = %bb1.i
  %5 = bitcast i8* %4 to %struct.C*               ; <%struct.C*> [#uses=1]
  %6 = bitcast i8* %4 to i32*                     ; <i32*> [#uses=1]
  store i32 5, i32* %6, align 4
  tail call void @__cxa_guard_release(i64* @guard variable for get()::c) nounwind
  br label %_Z3getv.exit

lpad.i:                                           ; preds = %bb1.i
  %eh_ptr.i = tail call i8* @llvm.eh.exception()  ; <i8*> [#uses=2]
  %eh_select12.i = tail call i32 (i8*, i8*, ...)* @llvm.eh.selector(i8* %eh_ptr.i, i8* bitcast (i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0 to i8*), i8* null) ; <i32> [#uses=0]
  tail call void @__cxa_guard_abort(i64* @guard variable for get()::c) nounwind
  tail call void @_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow(i8* %eh_ptr.i)
  unreachable

_Z3getv.exit:                                     ; preds = %invcont.i, %bb.i, %entry
  %_ZZ3getvE1c.0 = phi %struct.C* [ null, %bb.i ], [ %5, %invcont.i ], [ null, %entry ] ; <%struct.C*> [#uses=1]
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.C* %_ZZ3getvE1c.0, i64 0, i32 0 ; <i32*> [#uses=1]
  %8 = load i32* %7, align 4                      ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  ret i32 %8
}
```

Noteworth, no code is emitted for ::get, but main still allocates ::get::c (at %4) with a guard variable as needed (at %2 and at the end of invcont.i and lpad.i).  llvm here is inlining all of that stuff.

tl;dr: Don't worry about it, the optimizer normally gets this stuff right.  Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Well there's no use of `C` struct in `main()` after the initialization, calling `get()` has no side effects apart from initialization and returning reference to `c` which you don't keep. So there's no possible case where optimizing that line out makes the code behave differently ... hard to blame the compiler. This is similar to the original question, except we don't know what code after the call does.

Comment: no error yet, but dont want to find out the hard way.  thanks

Comment: If an optimization changes the behavior of your code, its either because you're doing something that is undefined (you aren't in this case) or because the optimizer is broken.

Comment: This doesn't look better; it adds an unnecessary level of indirection for all future uses of the class/struct.

Answer (score 1):

**Your original code is safe.**  Don't introduce an extra level of indirection (a pointer variable that has to get loaded before the address of the `std::map` is available.)

As Jerry Coffin says, your code has to run *as if* it ran in source order.  That includes running as-if it has constructed your boost or `std::mutex` and `std::map` before later stuff in main, such as starting threads.

Pre C++11, the language standard and memory model wasn't officially thread-aware, but stuff like this (thread-safe `static`-local initialization) worked anyway because compiler writers wanted their compilers to be useful.  e.g. GCC 4.1 from 2006 (https://godbolt.org/z/P3sjo4Tjd) still uses a guard variable with to make sure a single thread does the constructing in case multiple calls to `get()` happen at the same time.

Now, with C++11 and later, the ISO standard does include threads and it's officially required for that to be safe.

---

Since your program can't observe the difference, it's hypothetically possible that a compiler could choose to skip construction now let it happen in the first thread to actually call `get()` in a way that isn't optimized away.  **That's fine, construction of `static` locals is thread-safe**, with compilers like GCC and Clang using a "guard variable" that they check (read-only with an `acquire` load) at the start of the function.

A file-scope `static` variable would avoid the load+test/branch fast-path overhead of the guard variable that happens every call, and would be safe as long as nothing calls `get()` before the start of `main()`.  A guard variable  is pretty cheap especially on ISAs like x86, AArch64, and 32-bit ARMv8 that have cheap acquire loads, but more expensive on ARMv7 for example where an acquire load uses a `dmb ish` full barrier.

If some hypothetical compiler actually did the optimization you're worried about, the difference could be in NUMA placement of the page of .bss holding `static C c`, if nothing else in that page was touched first.  And potentially stalling other threads very briefly in their first calls to `get()` if construction isn't finished by the time a second thread also calls `get()`.

---

#### Current GCC and clang *don't* in practice do this optimization

Clang 17 with libc++ makes the following asm for x86-64, with `-O3`.  (demangled by [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BfoF2mA6Z9Y0ExZExcQlJCg1NLbntY31hA2VDiQCUtqhexMjsHAD0W%2BYAzGHI3lgA1CZ7bl4MJFjEmOgA%2BixMyefYJhoAgvuHx5hnFxYXgImFUbw%2B3zMBwYRy8p3Obmerz27y%2BRyYCgUJzcZwA7FYviciSdRugQCAgSDVCdKaCHucCZ9iSSCGSKS8EWECORBG8TugmA16XtGSZcQARBkQiE7UaCvDIM5fNzmABsJ2AmAIEEWeMZzLljkVONMIohzLuBDWDBOptFEulX0NCuxGtoqGiYgedplWxZ8tMyrVGq1Zh1evNxMt1rdHq9Pq%2BYslia%2BXJpTDC4bF%2BuJmu1iwZJx2JzwWLQLGSdDiJyod3%2BRBOqGSjhYeAAXv9VgQTgQEP9RLRaOcAGJK74Or4cZa0TgAVl4fg4WlIqE4Kss1hJq3W/32PFIBE0U%2BWAGsQHt/AA6ACc19V19xe1VZkfUP8Zln%2Bk4kgXR5XnF4BQQA0A8j2WOBYBgKAoIgJBy0regyAoCB4KreJGhYYAuD2MwQKwAA3BVMAANTwTAAHcAHlkkYTh9xoWgQWIICIGiP9ojCRoAE86N4DjmGILjKOibROkPbheHLNhBEohhaB4pdeCwaIvGANwxFoICJNILBniMcRFJ0vA7i6fDMC05dQU6YFNn3Llqj/Wg8GiYhuI8LA/wIYg8BYXjlioAxgAUUiKOo2jtP4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdRDN0JIDCMFBrGsfRnKAyBlibWoGC0gBaSi9hOEqAHUNMqlhkGSLxznFNAmlBEqmC4WdKtJZrgAYJqN0sKETl4VAzOIbysDynUqhqTIXAYdxPFaPQQlmUpyj0VJ0iKiY/C4fJdsyfpNqGQ6Oi6Oppn2vRLqKnomlOwZ4gum6VtyN7eme%2BZXuWBRtw2CRpznX9DNXDgTk%2BAAlABZE4AHE3BxbDLzMS8NBOCBcEIEgzihLhFl4cStEWZY%2ByYW5KFPEBZxAmcOB/UhF2XCHAOA0DFPAmC4NQCs0PIShUMQlB0qw3ENEOgiiJCqiaMXei6CYli2MM/juN40h1cE4TRIcTWpMYAhZPkv9lNU9TBy0/ddMMYADOXfATMcMyLN4KzkBszX7IZ5cnJctyME2ZcvJ8vy%2BEC4KyLl8L6NkaLxDiyL5CUNQ/10Q6xcyoabH9maCubTJSvKyqasHHrWX95r/dMHOK/QPqBqy4a9jGiapvM%2BB/uqMSFogVxbsO9aShe7aCj2j6DqOwoGB%2BraLp7q6GEe5pJ7uxeHumOfztsd6cinuUno20fCZWNYgdPhn52Zv8IZOVR/FVErVUkW0xZOLhcQxy8uCxnGiGIPjPYhNiZgRpnTL8jNeC%2BRfpeXEkh/AaH8HeC88DnxJBZmNACtgOYk2PJAsw0CQCwPgYg5BqpUGSHQTfcG2C8Hc3gBBRAIAuyNW5MhYWcQIisE2A/J%2BL8NTIEVKjQhQR8AALwGSQ6ycE6xWkMnRKacUoJFIORVyyRw5XzBqzTglFgRsMbFQKGcNEbIw/nsNGGMsYeH5ohIBZgiac1JuTTAlMhizTPBAhmTNMH/g4OzEC9DSBMNgiw/RwJBYoT5ghLhPDOB8Ofq/YAQjzFo3duIkgki9AyIHHI%2BKKckrpz0Gol4mjQY0J0RwPRBADGoCMQkgR6IjAfy/hoH%2B1joloSASApx%2BCKZUw8bTem34iF7FnGjWcXBrxcA0E%2BLgH49i4mvBUrB/icGBLAQQ0Z4yPxTJmXMhZSyVl%2BNAVzGmqouAY1mRoMwFDcS3NxBcwIDNW7HLZr0smWy3l0M2RNdIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D)).  The asm for `get()` is also inlined into `main`.  GCC with libstdc++ is pretty similar, really only differing in the `std::map` internals.

```
get():
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rip + guard variable for get()::c]  # all x86 loads are acquire loads
        test    al, al                       # check the guard variable
        je      .LBB0_1
        lea     rax, [rip + get()::c]        # retval = address of the static variable
   # end of the fast path through the function.
   # after the first call, all callers go through this path.
        ret

 # slow path, only reached if the guard variable is zero
.LBB0_1:
        push    rax
        lea     rdi, [rip + guard variable for get()::c]
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire@PLT
        test    eax, eax   # check if we won the race to construct c,
        je      .LBB0_3    # or if we waited until another thread finished doing it.

        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rip + get()::c+16], xmm0     # first 16 bytes of std::map<int,int> = NULL pointers
        movups  xmmword ptr [rip + get()::c], xmm0        # std::mutex = 16 bytes of zeros
        mov     qword ptr [rip + get()::c+32], 0          # another NULL
        lea     rsi, [rip + get()::c]                     # arg for __cxa_atexit
        movups  xmmword ptr [rip + get()::c+48], xmm0     # more zeros, maybe a root node?
        lea     rax, [rip + get()::c+48]                  
        mov     qword ptr [rip + get()::c+40], rax        # pointer to another part of the map object

        lea     rdi, [rip + C::~C() [base object destructor]]  # more args for atexit
        lea     rdx, [rip + __dso_handle]
        call    __cxa_atexit@PLT                 # register the destructor function-pointer with a "this" pointer

        lea     rdi, [rip + guard variable for get()::c]
        call    __cxa_guard_release@PLT          # "unlock" the guard variable, setting it to 1 for future calls
             # and letting any other threads return from __cxa_guard_acquire and see a fully-constructed object

.LBB0_3:                                     # epilogue
        add     rsp, 8
        lea     rax, [rip + get()::c]        # return value, same as in the fast path.
        ret
```

Even though the `std::map` is unused, constructing it involves calling `__cxa_atexit` (a C++-internals version of `atexit`) to register the destructor to free the red-black tree as the program exits.  I suspect this is the part that's opaque to the optimizer and the main reason it doesn't get optimized like `static int x = 123;` or `static void *foo = &bar;` into pre-initialized space in `.data` with no run-time construction (and no guard variable).

Constant-propagation to avoid the need for any run-time initialization *is* what happens if `struct C` only includes `std::mutex`, which in GNU/Linux at least doesn't have a destructor and is actually zero-initialized.  (C++ before C++23 allowed early init even when that included *visible* side-effects.  This doesn't; compilers can still constant-propagate `static int local_foo = an_inline_function(123);` into some bytes in `.data` with no run-time call.)

GCC and Clang also don't optimize away the guard variable (if there's any run-time work to do), even though `main` doesn't start any threads at all, let alone before calling `get()`.  A constructor in some other compilation unit (including a shared library) could have started another thread that called `get()` at the same time `main` did.  (It's arguably a missed optimization with `gcc -fwhole-program`.)

---

If the constructors had any (potentially) *visible* side-effects, perhaps including a call to `new` since `new` is replaceable, compilers couldn't defer it because the C++ language rules say when the constructor is called in the abstract machine.  (Compilers are allowed to make some assumptions about `new`, though, e.g. clang with libc++ can optimize away `new` / `delete` for an unused `std::vector`.)

Classes like `std::unordered_map` (a hash table instead of a red-black tree) do use `new` in their constructor.

I was testing with `std::map<int,int>`, so the individual objects don't have destructors with visible side-effects.  A `std::map<Foo,Bar>` where `Foo::~Foo` prints something *would* make it matter when the static-local initializer runs, since that's when we call `__cxa_atexit`.  Assuming destruction order happens in reverse of construction, waiting until later to call `__cxa_atexit` could lead to it being destructed sooner, leading to `Foo::~Foo()` calls happening too soon, potentially before instead of after some other visible side effect.

**Or some other global data structure could maybe have references to the `int` objects inside a `std::map<int,int>`, and use those in its destructor.**  That wouldn't be safe if we destruct the `std::map` too soon.

(I'm not sure if ISO C++, or GNU C++, gives such ordering guarantees for sequencing of destructors.  But if it does, that would be a reason compilers couldn't normally defer construction when it involves registering a destructor.  And looking for that optimization in trivial programs isn't worth the cost in compile time.)

---

#### With file-scope `static` to avoid a guard variable

Notice the lack of a guard variable, making the fast path faster, especially for ISAs like ARMv7 that don't have a good way to do just an acquire barrier.                       https://godbolt.org/z/4bGx3Tasj -

```
static C global_c;     // It's not actually global, just file-scoped static

C& get2() {
    return global_c;
}
```

```
# clang -O3 for x86-64
get2():
      # note the lack of a load + branch on a guard variable
        lea     rax, [rip + global_c]
        ret

main:
      # construction already happened before main started, and we don't do anything with the address
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

```
# GCC -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a15     // a random ARMv7 CPU
get2():
        ldr     r0, .L81          @ PC-relative load
        bx      lr

@ somewhere nearby, between functions
.L81:
        .word   .LANCHOR0+52      @ pointer to struct C global_c

main:
        mov     r0, #0
        bx      lr
```

**The constructor code that does the stores and calls `__cxa_atexit` still exists**, it's just in a separate function called `_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp:` (clang) or `_GLOBAL__sub_I_get():` (GCC), which the compiler adds to a list of init functions to be called before `main`.

Function-scoped local vars are normally fine, the overhead is pretty minimal, especially on x86-64 and ARMv8.  But since you were worried about micro-optimizations like when `std::map` was constructed at all, I thought it was worth mentioning.  And to show the mechanism compilers use to make this stuff work under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the compiler optimizes the function call or not is basically unspecified behavior as per the Standard. An unspecified behavior is basically a behavior which is chosen from a set of finite possibilities, but the choice may not be consistent every time. In this case, the choice is 'to optimize' or 'not', which the Standard does not specify and the implementation is also not supposed to document, as it is a choice which may not be consistently taken by a given implementation.

If the idea is just to 'touch', will it help if we just add a dummy volatile variable and dummy increment it in each call

e.g

```
C& getC(){
   volatile int dummy;
   dummy++;
   // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: How do you define "first call"? In any case, the function here is quite simple that it can be entirely optimized out.

Comment: Sadly, Sutter mentions in one of his talks that a smart compiler would be able to discard the `volatile` qualifier in `dummy`. The rationale is that it can know for a fact that being on the stack it is not a variable that refers to special hardware. Also a pointer to the variable is not being passed to any other function, so the compiler can know for a fact that changes to `dummy` are only visible inside `getC`, and as such it could remove the `volatile`. After that if the compiler notices that the value is never used, it can completely remove the var. I don't know any compiler that does this.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: well, I Just tried it all out in llvm.  In one case, the volitile variable was removed, (leaving nothing more than a main { return 0 }, but in the other case, the volitile with increment was inlined into main with the rest of getC.  I think this goes to prove your point that you just can't know what's gonna happen!

Comment: After inlining `getC`, a volatile store or increment is separate from initializing `static C c;` which has a `std::map` member.  If the compiler was going to optimize away a call to its constructor before starting threads, the presence or absence of a `volatile` access before (or after) that wouldn't matter.  If your reasoning was based on doing all or none of the function, that's not how it works.